# Initializing non-static member array of size defined in a #define of class type without default ctor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have the following class:

```
//in some .h file
#define BARS_IN_FOO 5 //The only place where this number should be specified.
//All code should work when I change this

//in some .cpp file
struct Foo;
struct Bar { Foo & foo; Bar(Foo & foo) : foo{ foo } {} } //Cannot be default initialized

struct Foo {
    std::array<Bar, BARS_IN_FOO> myBars;
    Foo() :
        myBars{ } //Error. Cannot default initialize Bars.
    //I want to initialize all Bars with Bar{*this} but at this point I don't
    //know how many Bar initializers I should put in the myBar initializer list
    {}
}
```

So how should I initialize `Foo::myBars`? The number of `Bar`s is known at compile time but I just want to specify this number in one place (in the define preferably, other suggestions are welcome).

Usage of `Foo::mybars`:

- Size of it will never change during runtime but I haven't decided what the number will be yet but will be somewhere in the range [1..10] (or so) (number might change a lot during development).
- Element values will never change
  (always will be the same non-const objects).
- Relation ship between `Foo` and `Bar` is that of composition. A `Foo` is made out of `Bar`s and their lifetime is the same. `Bar` without a `Foo` and visa versa makes no sense.
- The `Foo` and `Bar` classes are part of performance critical code and their size will influence the memory footprint of the program a lot (80-90% of the memory footprint will be `Foo`s and `Bar`s).

Compiler: **MSVS2017 version 15.3**

Edit: Changing `std::array<Bar, BARS_IN_FOO> myBars;` to `Bar myBars[BARS_IN_FOO];` is also oke if this helps.

Important edit: All the ctors of `Bar` and `Foo` are public. This was a mistake. I changed this.

Comment: the `#define` is a red herring, the real problem is that `Bar` has no default constructor

Comment: Making a `Bar` without its containing `Foo` instance also makes no sense. Of course I can always change `Bar::Foo&` into `Bar::Foo*` and create the link at a later time (that is, in the body of `Foo::Foo()` after the initializer list) but I want to explore other options first.

Comment: A Bar that contains a reference to a Foo that contains an array of Bars that contains a reference to a Foo ... ? When will this end?

Comment: A `Foo` consists of `Bar`s and a `Bar` knows its parent `Foo`.

Comment: @manni66 I suspect it ends right there. A `Foo` with an array of `Bars` which each have a reference to that `Foo`.

Comment: I am not clear on what the question is.  You have a default constructor for Foo.  You have a constant (can be #define or const var) specifying how many there should be.  You know the pointer to Foo which must be passed to the Bar constructor (this).  So what are you missing?

Comment: Is the problem the aggregate initialization?

Comment: @BasyaPerlman Yes! The initialization of the `Bar` array

Comment: Do you have control of the Bar class?  Can you change it?

Comment: @BasyaPerlman They are my own classes so yes. Are you referring to the fact that everything is private? This was a mistake. See my edit

Comment: No, I had an idea but after looking at it more I don't think I was correct.

Comment: Is `Bar` movable/copyable?

Comment: @NirFriedman yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily if you can assume that `Bar` is movable/copyable:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::array<Bar, sizeof...(Is)> make_bar_array_impl(Foo& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return { (Is, f)... };
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::array<Bar, N> make_bar_array(Foo& f) {
    return make_bar_array_impl(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

Foo() : myBars(make_bar_array<BARS_IN_FOO>(*this)) {}
```

This could easily refactored to use a more generic template metaprogramming utility of "repetition". I suspect that any template meta programming library will have some such utility, here I don't bother factoring it out since it is a one liner anyhow. But if you come across such problems often it's something to consider (just write a function that returns an N-entry initializer list all with the same expression).

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aab004c0090cc144. Sorry couldn't easily access an MSVC compiler. Also compiled with 14 since I didn't need any 17 features.

Edit: even if `Bar` is not movable/copyable, or if you don't think things will get optimized, this technique can actually be modified to work even in that case. You can generate an `array<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>, N` instead. But this is a little bit more complex and typically in C++ most things should be movable, and usually constructor calls are not in the critical path. Still I can elaborate if necessary.

Edit2: also, please don't use a #define for that. `constexpr static auto BARS_IN_FOO = 5;` should work exactly the same way, except that it is properly namespaced (and probably some other macro nastiness I'm forgetting).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to build a char array (or a byte array in C++ 17) and use a pointer from there to have a Bar array. An union with a single Bar is enough to ensure proper alignment:

```
#include <iostream>


#define BARS_IN_FOO 5

// X is the type of the "array", Y the type of its initializer, n the size
template<class X, class Y = X, int n = 1>
class InitArr {
    union {
        X initial;                          // guarantee correct alignment
        char buffer[n * sizeof(X)];         // only to reserve enough place
    };
public:
    InitArr(Y& inival): initial(inival) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            new(&initial + i)X(inival);     // properly construct an X at &initial +i
                                            // which is guaranteed to be inside buffer
        }
    }
    X& operator[] (int i) {                 // make InitArr behave like an array
        X* arr = &initial;
        return arr[i];                      // could add control that  0 <= i < n
    }
};

struct Foo;
struct Bar { Foo & foo; Bar(Foo & foo) : foo{ foo } {} }; //Cannot be default initialized

struct Foo {
    InitArr<Bar, Foo, BARS_IN_FOO> myBars;
    Foo() :
        myBars{ *this }
        //I want to initialize all Bars with Bar{*this} 
    {}
};
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << &foo << std::endl;
    // shows that all foo.myBars[i] point to the original foo
    for (int i = 0; i < BARS_IN_FOO; i++) {
        std::cout << &(foo.myBars[i].foo) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As the X are constructed in place, everything is acceptable for any C++11 compiler and you get a true random access container. There is no Undefined Behaviour, because the memory was reserved by the char array, and the objects are correctly constructed there. This is a generic trick to delay a complex member initialization inside the constructor with the full power of the language, when thing become hard to do with a mere initializer or with compile time meta-programming.

---

Here is my original idea left here for reference but really less nice...

You could try to build a custom *recursive* array, to allow initialization of all of its elements from the same value:

```
// X is the type of the "array", Y the type of its initializer, n the size
template<class X, class Y=X, int n = 1>
class RArr {
public:
    X first;
    RArr<X, Y, n-1> other;

    RArr(Y& i) : first(i), other(i) {}
    X& operator [] (int i) {
        if (i >= n || i < 0) throw std::domain_error("Out of range");
        if (i == 0) return first;
        return other[i - 1];
    }
};

// specialization for n=1
template <class X, class Y> 
class RArr<X, Y, 1> {
public:
    X first;
    RArr(Y& i) : first(i) {}
    X& operator [] (int i) {
        if (i != 0) throw std::domain_error("Out of range");
        return first;
    }
};

struct Foo;
struct Bar { Foo & foo; Bar(Foo & foo) : foo{ foo } {} }; //Cannot be default initialized

struct Foo {
    RArr<Bar, Foo, BARS_IN_FOO> myBars;
    Foo() :
        myBars{ *this } 
                 //I want to initialize all Bars with Bar{*this} 
    {}
};
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << &foo << std::endl;
    // shows that all foo.myBars[i] point to the original foo
    for (int i = 0; i < BARS_IN_FOO; i++) {
        std::cout << &(foo.myBars[i].foo)  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well it works as per your requirements but is pretty useless as is because all the `Bar` elements refere to the same `Foo`. It will only make sense when `Bar` class will contain other members.

Comment: A very creative solution! Memory layout also seems alright. The only disadvantage of this approach is that `RArr` isn't a random-access container anymore. The time complexity of element access went from O(1) to O(n). It resembles a singly linked list but without its advantages (and without some disadvantages as well like horrible cache coherency). This might be solved with some nasty memory management tricks (casting an `RArr` to an `X` array and indexing into that array for example). Better way could be putting an `RArr` into a union together with an `X` array. I'll try that now.

Comment: @Jupiter: Your idea of union to have a true random-access container lead me to the right path. The correct solution is much simpler!

Comment: I'm not sure if I think that messing around with new and aliasing char arrays to be an improvement over template metaprogramming...

Comment: @NirFriedman: I agree that your solution is nicer than my rather C-ish one... It is an old trick now with all the meta-programming features of recent standards, but I prefere to leave it here for readers forced to use older compilers.